# disk corruption [wrong link/formatting]

Tags: arch-linux

after partitioning my harddisk i accidentally did

```
mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/nvme0n1
```

which is the place for the for harddisk

i should have said

```
mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/nvme0n1p1
```

so now, when typing the command **cgdisk** i get error message "could not load partitions from 'dev/nvme0n1'!aborting!

screenshot of **gdisk**[image]

[image]
[image]
what should i do now?

i pressed **2**
then i pressed **v**
but i don't know how to proceed ...

Answer (score 0):

You overwrote the main GPT partition table with the metadata of a FAT32 filesystem. Fortunately, the GPT partition table scheme includes a backup copy of the partition table at the very end of the disk, which probably survived untouched.

You should select `2`, then `r` for the recovery/transformation menu, then `c` to use the backup GPT partition table to reconstruct the primary one, `p` to display the partition table, then if **you** think it makes sense, finally press `w` to save it to the disk and exit `gdisk`.

After that, you should be ready to create filesystems again. Just make sure you target the partition device this time, instead of the whole-disk device.

Comment: could you maybe give advice on which commands to type? i'm really lost here :(

Comment: Please see my edit above.